# Laravel redirecting to the previous page

Tags: laravel

I am inserting data to the `database` and redirecting back to the previous page using the code below in `laravel`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $todo=new Todo;
    $todo->todo=$request->todo;
    $todo->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

See My web page [image]

After entering some data "new todo" it works well; data inserted and shows in the page but the page becomes like below.
I think the stylings are not working in the page

[image: See the image]

And after refreshing the page i got the page well.
What should be the problem?

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
return back()->withInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previous URL in **session** so that you can easily redirect back to their previous URL,

Try this in your function,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('url.intended',url()->previous());
    $todo=new Todo;
    $todo->todo=$request->todo;
    $todo->save();
    return redirect($request->session()->get('url.intended'));
}
```

Here, the Previous URL is generated by [Helpers function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#urls) of laravel.

Please comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have no doubt about your solution.But what is the problem with my code?its redirecting to the same url but not working well after redirecting

Comment: `return redirect()->back();`  this code will redirect you back like you press back button in browser and css come from cache. And if you store your previous URL in session and redirect it will load the page from scratch with all CSS loading. And If  you find my answer helpful you can accept my answer and upvote too :).

Comment: Though i did not get my answer its helpful.Thank you

Comment: So which answer you are finding?

Comment: Why are the stylings are not working in the redirected page?

Comment: Anyway, if you are using my code, stylings load perfectly?

Comment: Great then. Happy for you :)